# How do I get number of products for each tag

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using loopback js with mongodb.
I have a product collection like:

```
{
  name:'prod 1',
  tags:['tag1','tag3']
},
{
  name:'prod 2',
  tags:['tag2']
},
{
  name:'prod 3',
  tags:['tag2','tag3']
}
```

I need to find the number of products grouped by tags, something like
Expected result:

```
{
  tag1 : 1,
  tag2 : 2,
  tag3 : 2
}
```

I tried to achieve this like:

```
productCollection.aggregate(
                        {$match: {
                            is_available: true
                        } },
                        {$unwind:"$tags"},
                        { $group : {
                            _id:"$tags",
                            "products" : { "$sum" : 1 }
                            }
                        },function(err,totals){});
```

But the above is grouping based on the entire `tags` property and not each individual tag. What am I missing? Do I somehow need to unwind and project it?

Comment: What is your current o/p?

Comment: Your query is already producing the expected result. I didn't understand why you are saying it is not producing the expected result. The query has not been changed in the below answer as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count array occurrences across all documents with mongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089056/count-array-occurrences-across-all-documents-with-mongo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are couple of ways to get result you desired. However if you are expecting precise document format, try in mongo shell.

```
var obj = {};

db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$tags"},
    {$group:{_id:"$tags", count:{$sum:1}}}
]).forEach(function(doc){
    obj[doc._id] = doc.count;
});

printjson(obj);
```

This should emit.

```
{ 
    "tag1" : NumberInt(1), 
    "tag3" : NumberInt(2), 
    "tag2" : NumberInt(2)
}
```

Hopefully, will give you some directions.