# How to Change output format when using group in aggregation mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I Need to change the out put format of following mongodb query.

**Query**

```
 db.Response.aggregate([{
       "$match": {
         "$and": [{
           "job_details.owner_id" : 482,
         }, {
           "job_details.owner_type" : 'searches',
         }],
       },
   }, 
   {
      "$group": {
         "_id": "$candidate_sublocation_name_string",
         "count": {
           "$sum": 1,
         },
      },
   }])
```

**Actual Out Put**

```
{ "_id" : "Central Delhi ", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Adyar ", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Bommanahalli", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "DLF Phase 3 ", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "Aai Colony", "count" : 1 }
```

**Needed Out Put**

```
 { "Central Delhi" : 1 }
    { "Adyar" : 1 }
    { "Bommanahalli" : 2 }
    { "DLF Phase 3 ": 2 }
    { "Aai Colony": 1 }
```

Is it possible to change the out put format like this..?

Comment: No, I dont think its possible through standard aggregation pipeline methods.

Comment: [Why do you want to use your data as key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089056/count-array-occurrences-across-all-documents-with-mongo)

Comment: This data for displaying facet count    like

Comment: This data for displaying facet count    like  Adyar(1),  Adyar(2) .    for development i using three tier architecture Frond end(php) then Api(python) then mongodb . When i converting the data to  j son format that structure is very expensive.  so i need to reduce the size of json .   If it is not possible i will do in python (api)

Comment: @SuFi Like Veeram said it's not possible in aggregation. I don't understand why the conversion is expensive. The differences between the JSON's is not that big. _id (3 chars) count (5 chars) per line. Is there an other problem that makes the operation expensive ?

Comment: @ HoefMeistert. that only the problem. But my collection is huge huge. at time fetching millions of  rows.    can u please give me your mail id.