# Mongo group aggregation: produce a dictionary of keys instead of an array with _ids

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, aggregation-framework

Let's say we have the following book collection from MongoDB's [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) documentation:

```
{ "_id" : 8751, "title" : "The Banquet", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 8752, "title" : "Divine Comedy", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 8645, "title" : "Eclogues", "author" : "Dante", "copies" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 7000, "title" : "The Odyssey", "author" : "Homer", "copies" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 7020, "title" : "Iliad", "author" : "Homer", "copies" : 10 }
```

If we follow their example, and group by author like so:

```
db.books.aggregate(
   [
     { $group : { _id : "$author", books: { $push: "$title" } } }
   ]
)
```

then we get an array back:

```
[
  { "_id" : "Homer", "books" : [ "The Odyssey", "Iliad" ] },
  { "_id" : "Dante", "books" : [ "The Banquet", "Divine Comedy", "Eclogues" ] }
]
```

But I would prefer have a **dictionary** instead of an **array**:

```
{
  "Homer": { "books" : [ "The Odyssey", "Iliad" ] },
  "Dante": { "books" : [ "The Banquet", "Divine Comedy", "Eclogues" ] }
}
```

In other words, I want to use the `_id` as keys in a dictionary.  That will be easier for the receiver to access, as they won't need to search through the array when they want to look up a particular author.

Obviously the receiver could re-arrange the data when they get it.  But is there any way to do it through Mongo's aggregation pipeline?

---

(For bonus marks, output nested dictionaries when the `_id` has multiple properties, e.g. a key for each publisher and then below the publisher a key for each author.)

Comment: Nope, its not possible through standard pipeline operators to project id values as keys for your output. I'm afraid you'll have to do this on client side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [count array occurrences across all documents with mongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089056/count-array-occurrences-across-all-documents-with-mongo)

Comment: What you are trying to do is use your data as key which is what the possible duplicate asked. It doesn't matter if the output is array or not.

Comment: I added some clarification and explanation to the question

Comment: If you need more flexibility than the aggregation framework allows, you can use map-reduce. Map-reduce will be able to generate the type of result your are looking for.

Comment: Highly unlikely to achieve this, Aggregation pipeline at all stages of pipeline streaming return an array of document, in whatever format. What you are asking is that instead of array, it should be a (javascript) object. I am sure it can't be achieved through aggregation at least.Maybe it can be modified to return a single document inside the array which looks like the dictionary.

Comment: OK thanks for the confirmation that this is not possible. I have had two situations where I wanted it, and expect to have more. But no problem, I will just re-arrange the data when I receive it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need more flexibility than the aggregation framework allows, you can try using map-reduce

```
map = function() {
  var books = {};
  books[this._id] = this.title;
  emit(this.author, books);
}

reduce = function(key, values) {
  var result = {};
  values.forEach(function(value) {
    for (var id in value) {
       result[id] = value[id];
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I may try the map-reduce approach some time.

For now I am processing the data when I receive it, in Javascript:

```
/**
 * Flattens an array of items with _ids into an object, using the _ids as keys.
 *
 * For example, given an array of the form:
 *
 *     [
 *       { _id: 'X', foo: 'bar' },
 *       { _id: 'Y', foo: 'baz' }
 *     ]
 *
 * Will produce an object ("dictionary") of the form:
 *
 *     {
 *       X: { foo: 'bar' },
 *       Y: { foo: 'baz' }
 *     }
 *
 * Note that the `_id` properties will be removed from the input array!
 */
function flattenBy_id (array) {
    const obj = {};
    array.forEach(item => {
        const id = item._id;

        if (typeof id !== 'string' && typeof id !== 'number' && typeof id !== 'boolean') {
            throw Error(`Cannot flatten: _id is non-primitive (${typeof id}) in item: ${JSON.stringify(item)}`);
        }

        delete item._id;
        obj[id] = item;
    });
    return obj;
}
```

A similar result could be produced in **one line using LoDash**:

```
_.keyBy(array, '_id')
```

But that would not remove the `_id` properties, which is cleaner for my purposes.

---

Here is a version that creates nested objects when the `_id` has multiple properties:

```
/**
 * Flattens an array of items with _ids into an object, using the _ids as keys.
 *
 * For example, given an array of the form:
 *
 *     [
 *       { _id: {publisher: 'P', author: 'Q', book: 'Alice in Wonderland'},   date: 1940, content: '...' },
 *       { _id: {publisher: 'X', author: 'Y', book: 'The Hobbit'},            date: 1950, content: '...' },
 *       { _id: {publisher: 'X', author: 'Y', book: 'The Lord of the Rings'}, date: 1960, content: '...' },
 *       { _id: {publisher: 'X', author: 'Z', book: 'Harry Potter'},          date: 1990, content: '...' },
 *     ]
 *
 * Will produce an object ("dictionary") of the form:
 *
 *     {
 *       P: {
 *         Q: {
 *           'Alice in Wonderland':   {date: 1940, content: '...'}
 *         }
 *       },
 *       X: {
 *         Y: {
 *           'The Hobbit':            {date: 1950, content: '...'},
 *           'The Lord of the Rings': {date: 1960, content: '...'}
 *         },
 *         Z: {
 *           'Harry Potter':          {date: 1990, content: '...'}
 *         }
 *       }
 *     }
 *
 * Note that the `_id` properties will be removed from the input array!
 */
function flattenBy_id (array) {
    const dictionary = {};
    array.forEach(item => {
        const path = item._id;

        const pathArray = typeof path === 'object' ? Object_values(path) : [path];

        let target = dictionary;

        pathArray.forEach((key, i) => {
            // Check that key is a primitive
            // Not throwing on 'undefined' because we sometimes have (very old) data with that key
            if (typeof key !== 'string' && typeof key !== 'number' && typeof key !== 'boolean') {
                throw Error(`Cannot flatten: _id is non-primitive (${typeof key}) in item: ${safeStringify(item)}`);
            }

            // Are we on the final step of the path, or before it?
            if (i < pathArray.length - 1) {
                // We are not at the end of the path.  Travel one step.
                if (target[key] === undefined) {
                    target[key] = {};
                }
                target = target[key];
            } else {
                // We are on the final step of the path

                // We don't want to overwrite data that already exists.  We should never be given input of that form.
                if (target[key] !== undefined) {
                    throw Error(`Cannot flatten: The key "${key}" already appears in ${safeStringify(target)} while trying to add: ${safeStringify(item._id)}`);
                }

                delete item._id;
                target[key] = item;
            }
        });

    });
    return dictionary;
}
```

It assumes that the `_id` properties are always in the same order. Hopefully that is consistent behaviour of Mongo's `$group` operator.

It will not work well, and possibly throw an error, if the `_id` does not always contain the same number of properties.  (For example `_id: {foo: 1, bar: 2}` followed by `_id: {foo: 1}` will cause trouble.  This can happen if `bar` is undefined for some documents.)  If you have data of that type, a different approach will be needed.