# Mongo count array item occurrences across all collection documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection where each document has an array with multiple hashtags (a simple string). I would like to count how many times each hashtag has appeared and return something like this:

```
{hashtag: "hashtag1",
 count: numOcurrences
}
{hashtag: "hashtag2",
 count: numOcurrences
}
...
```

It seems similar to this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089056/count-array-occurrences-across-all-documents-with-mongo), but since I don't want to filter by any parameter, just count the overall occurrences I think It has to be a cleaner way to solve this, sadly my mongo knowledge is very limited...

The collection which the hashtags are in, looks similar to this, being the field "hastag" the array of hashtags:

```
{"_id": ...,
 "hashtag" : [
   "hashtag1",
    "hashtag2"
  ],
 "likes" : ...
},
{"_id": ...,
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is a bit easier than the other problem you mentioned, and you could solve it using the aggregation below:

```js
db.hashtags.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$hashtag"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$hashtag",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  // you can skip this projection if it's okay for you to have the result like [{ _id: "hashtag1", count: 2 }]
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "hashtag": "$_id",
      "count": 1
    }
  }
])
```

You can see a working example in [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nUq82LNn2Fw)

Comment: Thanks very much, it was exactly that!